# No module named 'psycopg2' on aws lambda. What is the best way to solve this?

Tags: aws-lambda

This is my `requirements.txt` file:

```
hvac==0.9.5
psycopg2-binary==2.8.3
```

I don't know what else I can do. I'm not really understanding what the problem is:

> psycopg2 needs to be build and compiled with statically linked libraries for Linux.

But why does it work locally? I guess it's because pip is building and compiling it for macos? Is that right?

What can I do to solve this problem? Does building and compiling the library and including the folder in my serverless deploy the best way to go about this? Is that the best way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lambda does not run your `requirements.txt` file to download dependencies. You have to package those dependencies in your Lambda deployment artifact. For binary dependencies like psycopg2, they have to be statically compiled in an Amazon Linux VM so that they will work in the Lambda runtime environment. This is documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html).

For the specific library you are using, someone has already created a version that will work on AWS Lambda [here](https://github.com/jkehler/awslambda-psycopg2).

Alternatively, you could add a Lambda Layer to your function that includes psycopg2. Someone has already created one for you [here](https://github.com/revmischa/psycopg2-lambda-layer).